# Is one of these solved problems incorrect?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

I am currently learning about the Lorentz transformations. So I compared two solved problems from two different textbooks in order to see how the Lorentz transformations are applied. I got confused because I believe the two problems imply two different conclusions to what seems to be two analogous problems. Let's look at the first one.

$\textbf{First Problem:}$

The following problem is taken from Hugh Young's and Roger Freeman's University Physics with Modern Physics, 13th edition, example 37.6:

[image]

NOTE: Im only looking at the length variables for now as the next problem only looks at the length variable.

As expected, we obtain the locations of events 1 and 2 via the Inverse Lorentz transformation.

$$x_1 = \gamma(x'_1 +vt'_1) = \frac{0 +0.600c(0)}{\sqrt{1 -0.600^2}}\text{ m} = 0$$

$$x_2 = \gamma(x'_2 +vt'_2) = \frac{-300 +0.600c(0)}{\sqrt{1 -0.600^2}}\text{ m} = -375\text{ m}$$

$\textbf{Second Problem:}$

The following problem is taken from the online version of Openstax's University Physics Volume 3, taken on 07/OCT/2022, example 5.7 (Can be accessed here: https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-3/pages/5-5-the-lorentz-transformation):

[image]

Here, the second problem is, to my understanding, analogous to the first one. However, what I see from the second problem is a length contraction, whereas on the first problem, I see a length dilation. So one of them must be wrong or at least erroneous. I suspect it is the second one.

Here, I take that the surveyor takes two measurements. $(x_1, t_1), (x_2, t_2)$ such that $\Delta x = x_2 -x_1 = 100\text{ m}$.

I also noticed that the problem uses the following equation:

$$x_2 -x_1 = \frac{x'_2 +vt}{\sqrt{1 -v^2/c^2}} -\frac{x'_1 +vt}{\sqrt{1 -v^2/c^2}}$$

Which implies

$$x_1 = \frac{x'_1 +vt}{\sqrt{1 -v^2/c^2}}$$

and

$$x_2 = \frac{x'_2 +vt}{\sqrt{1 -v^2/c^2}}$$

From the Lorentz transformations we see that:

$$x_1 = \frac{x'_1 +vt'_1}{\sqrt{1 -v^2/c^2}}$$

and that

$$x_2 = \frac{x'_2 +vt'_2}{\sqrt{1 -v^2/c^2}}$$

The equations above assume that $vt = vt'_2 = vt'_1$ and therefore $t'_2 = t'_1$, which, I believe, is not always the case as $t'_2$ and $t'_1$ depend on $t_1$ and $t_2$, respectively. Moreover, the problem does not give the assumption that $t'_2 = t'_1$ or any data regarding $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Is it fair to say that solved problem 2 is erroneous, since we do not have enough observations/data about time in frame S to make inferrences about space in frame S'? (In relativity time and space are not independent of each other afterall)

$\textbf{A question:}$

This leads me to another thought. Let's go back to the first solved problem. Although it is what I expected given my understanding of the Lorentz transformations, from Stanley's perspective, the spaceship is travelling at a speed of 0.600c. If my understanding of length contraction is correct, shoudn't stanley observe the length of the ship to be $300\sqrt{1 -0.6^2}\text{ m} = 240\text{ m}$? Because this seems to be a length dilation. I wonder if anyone can give me an intuition regarding this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both problems are correct.  The issue is that they're not talking about the same thing.  In particular, in the first problem, the pair of events considered is the same between the two frames;  while in the second problem, it's a different pair of events in each frame.

In the first problem, it is hopefully evident that there are only two events being considered:  the front of the spaceship crossing the finish line (Event $A$), and the message being emitted from the back of the spaceship (Event $B$).  The Lorentz transformation is then being applied to find the coordinates of these events in one frame given their coordinates in the other frame.

But there's an important difference in the second problem.  Whenever we say "the length of an object in frame $S$", we mean "the distance between two simultaneous events on the worldlines of the object's ends."  Suppose that in frame $S$, events $A$ and $B$ (on the worldlines of the object's ends) are simultaneous.  The length as measured in frame $S$ will then be the spatial distance between $A$ and $B$ (in that frame.)

But in a different frame $S'$, event $B$ is not simultaneous with $A$!  Instead, there is another event $B'$, on the same worldline as $B$, that is simultaneous with $A$ in the frame $S'$.  And in the frame $S'$, the length of the object is the spatial separation between $A$ and $B'$, not $A$ and $B$.  Since we're not considering the same pair of events in both frames, there is no reason to believe that the two spatial separations will be related in the same way they were in the first problem;  and indeed, we do not get the same result.

As a general rule, *the way to avoid "paradoxes" in special relativity is to carefully phrase everything in terms of "events".*  In the above example, carefully defining the idea of "length" in terms of simultaneous events makes it clear that the events in question must be different in different frames.

Comment: "Instead, there is another event B′, on the same worldline as B, that is simultaneous with A in the frame S′. And in the frame S′, the length of the object is the spatial separation between A and B′, not A and B. " Aaah Thank you for this. Everything is clear now.